# Stress test of many users accounts with JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I want to perform a stress test on different cases for my web application with JMeter.
I have a small network and each PC has a large number of user accounts.
I have configured JMeter to produce the same network footprint as the browser and I can record the requests generated by browser using JMeter's HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder.
What is the next step? Do I have to create test plan for each case with Samplers and Listeners (Load TEsting) or just increase the number of users and check for errors at the Graph Result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to simulate real-life activity of each real user, if all of them are doing the same actions - it's sufficient to implement these actions. If different users are doing different actions - it makes sense to move these actions into different [Thread Groups](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group)

Stress Test assumes finding the limits of your application so I would suggest the following approach:

1. Start with 1 user
2. Gradually increase the load at the same time looking into [Response Times Over Time](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ResponseTimesOverTime/) and [Transactions per Second](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/TransactionsPerSecond/) charts
3. Up to certain load response time will remain the same and throughput will be increasing at the same factor as the number of users does, when response time will start growing and transactions per second will decrease it will indicate that you reached the [saturation point](http://hd-performance.blogspot.com/2010/05/saturation-point.html) and that would be the maximum of users which your system can support.

Try to [avoid using listeners as they don't add any value, just consume resources](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/greedy-listeners-memory-leeches-performance-testing/), you should be [running your test in non-GUI mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui) and when the test finishes either use listeners to open and analyze .jtl results file or generate [HTML reporting dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html)

Comment: https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-run-a-stress-test-in-jmeter?utm_source=dzone&utm_medium=article&utm_campaign=jmeter-tutorials-cluster                                                     I should have read your article before I ask..  It's very helpful. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You need to first find out how many users you need to simulate. Once you have found out you can use on PC or try distributed environment

https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-perform-distributed-testing-in-jmeter

Once the test is complete you can check the test results Aggregate report and other graphs like response time , Active users, transactions etc. As Dmitri suggested HTML reporting is a good way to see the results too.